# Why this onTouchEvent doesnt work?

Tags: android, touch-event

There is a ImageButton in my project. I create a onTouchEvent that when user touch inside the ImageButton a sound is played. But it doesn't work.

```
  @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){      

      ImageButton img_1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img_1_);       
      Rect r = new Rect();
  img_1.getDrawingRect(r);

     if(r.contains((int)event.getX(),(int)event.getY())){

        if(firstTime == true){
              firstTime = false;
          snd.play_s_l_9(); 
              System.out.println("Touch In Image");
          }
      }

             if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
          //When we lift finger reset the firstTime flag
          firstTime = true;
               }

       return true;
}
```

Comment: Do you add this listener to your ImageButton?

Comment: @ben75, No I didn't see it.

Comment: Mahdi if the answers solve your problem accept them by clicking on the tick mark next to the answer , it will give motive to the others to help you more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `Activity` implements `OnTouchListener`, simply call

```
yourImageButton.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

to register the listener with the `ImageButton`. Hope this helps.